# Differences between initializing variable from angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

**Method 1**

```
export class CartComponent {

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService
  ) { }

    items = this.cartService.getItems();
}
```

**Method 2**

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit{

   constructor(
    private cartService: CartService
  ) { }

  items: Product[] = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.cartService.getItems();
  }
}
```

Both methods allow me to init items but which method is correct? And what are the differences between the methods?

Comment: Angular services do not have lifecycle hooks like components do. Lifecycle hooks in Angular are methods that allow you to tap into specific points in the lifecycle of a component or directive, such as initialization, change detection, or destruction.

However, services in Angular do have their own lifecycle. They are typically created when an application starts and destroyed when the application is closed, but there are no specific lifecycle hooks provided for services like there are for components.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

However, when using the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook to initialize a variable, it is preferable. Especially if your variable is related to the component's input or an asynchronous operation, you should use `Method 2`.

You can check about this in [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-choose-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-your-angular-apps-f16987627312).

Answer (score 0):

Service can be injected(specified as constructor parameter) by multiple components, pipes, services, etc. If you need to share some variable(or method) - move it to service, otherwise there is no objective reason to move variable(or method) to service.

Also, knowing which concrete service to inject or which API method to call is not presentation logic, and it is preferable to have only presentation logic in most components and only some components with business(or other) logic. It may be better to have component which doesn't know anything but which methods it needs to present data and handle inputs, and take concrete method implementations from outside, like

```js
export class SomeComponent {
  @Input({required: true}) vm: ISomeComponentViewModel;
  ...
}

export interface ISomeComponentViewModel {
  getItems$(): Observable<ISomeComponentItem[]>;
  updateItem$(
    item: ISomeComponentItem,
    update$: (currentItem) => Observable<ISomeComponentUpdateResult>
  ): Observable<ISomeComponentUpdateResult>;
}
```

But notice that it is better to separate presentation and other logic on first need, like when we have combobox for selection of some item which takes data from remote API, and we just received requirement to have combobox which looks same, but takes items from local memory, or somewhat different remote API